# keyboard shortcut for showing proposal table for solving errors using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

When a row contains an error, Eclipse display an error icon on the left. If you click on that icon a proposal table is showed and lists some possible solutions, if the jvm finds any.

Is possible to activate the proposed problem solution list, using a shortcut from the keyboard?

Comment: I had to `window/preferences/general/keys/"content assist" (*)` in 2014. `ctrl+1` didn't work, not even with `shift` added. Maybe I just have a misconfigured Eclipse, not sure. Anyway, the big thing seems to be to find out they're called 'proposal' or 'assist' in the first place.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> on azerty keyboards) is the standard binding